# Display all comments for each blog posts

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, foreach

I have php codes to display all comments for each blog post. I used a join that was the same blog as well as one comment which was not effective.
I decided to settle with these codes but unfortunately i am only able to display the first comment but not the rest of the comments associated with the blog.

These are my codes below:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$postData = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM blog_posts") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
$commentData = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM comment") or die(mysqli_error()); 
$posts = array();     
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($postData)) {
    $posts[] = $row; 
    $commentrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($commentData);
    $comment[] = $commentrow; 
    echo '<h3>' . $row['title'] . '</h3>';
    echo '<h5>' . $row['author'] . ', ' . '</h5>';
        echo '<blockquote>';
        echo '<b>Comments</b><br />';
        foreach($comment as $comments) {
            if($row['id']==$comments['blog_posts_id']) {
                $comment_excerpt = substr($comments['comment'],0,100);
                echo '<br>' . $comment_excerpt . '<br>'; 
                }
            }            
        echo '</blockquote>';

    }
```

Kindly help here.